# Mapster - mapping descendant classes from base class

Tags: mapping, automapper, descendant, mapster

Classes:

```
public class Department
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentA : Department
{
    public string NameA { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
DepartmentA departmentA = new DepartmentA { NameA = "depA", Name = "dep" };

Employee emp = new Employee
{
        Name = "James",
        Salary = 20000,
        Address = "London",
        Department = departmentA
};
        
//Mapster
var empDTO = emp.Adapt<EmployeeDTO>();

//AutoMapper
//var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDTO>());

//var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
//EmployeeDTO empDTO = mapper.Map<EmployeeDTO>(emp);

Console.WriteLine("SourceType:" + emp.Department.GetType().Name);

Console.WriteLine("DestType:" + empDTO.Department.GetType().Name);
```

If you run the code you will see that SourceType and DestType are not the same. How do I achieve that they are the same? Mapster mapps department as Department class (ancestor) and not as DepartmentA class (descendant).
In this example I know that there is descendant in emp.Department but in my app I won't know. So the solution of this problem must be generic.
<s>I tried to solve this problem in AutoMapper. Got the same results.</s> As @Prolog wrote below, in AutoMapper is working. I updated main code.
 I am still interested if someone solved issue in Mapster.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem using AutoMapper. It successfully maps employee to DTO with destination of the same type `DepartmentA`. Check it again please.

Comment: @Prolog: you are right. It is working with automapper. I just made another sample on different computer (right now I can not access the original example). I will update code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [ShallowCopyForSameType](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Shallow-merge#deep-copy-vs-shallow-copy), AutoMapper will perform deep copy only declared types, Mapster perform deep copy for all types.